# I have date function to create for entering date and to create random time i want to combine both of them

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

hi dear i have a query which create dates for specic lenght which is mentioned and a query which is create random time want to join both for date generating is this
It create dates for specific lenght and insert into table query is

```
insert into calendar_date2  
with dates as (  
  select date'2019-12-31'+level dt  
  from   dual  
  connect by level <= 365  
)  
  select dt,   
         case   
           when to_char(dt, 'fmday') in ('sunday')   
           then 'N' else 'Y'  
         end  
  from dates
;
```

what it will do is enter `CALENDER_DATE2` all dates mentioned on connect by level

2nd query is to genrate random time

```
with test (start_date) as
   (select to_date('01.01.2021 07:45', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
 )
 select start_date + round(dbms_random.value(1, 15)) / (24 * 60) result
 from test
 connect by level <= 15
```

I want to write both query work together what i wrote which is not working for me that is

```
insert into calendar_date2  
with dates as (  
  select dates(to_date('01.01.2020 07:45', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'))+level dt  
  from   dual
select start_date + round(dbms_random.value(1, 15)) / (24 * 60) result
 from test  
  connect by level <= 365  
)  
  select dt,   
         case   
           when to_char(dt, 'fmday') in ('sunday')   
           then 'N' else 'Y'  
         end  
  from dates
;
```

i write this but it not worked for me please help struck here from past many hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
insert into calendar_date2 (dt, is_workday )
SELECT dt,
       DECODE( TRUNC( dt ) - TRUNC( dt, 'IW' ), 6, 'N', 'Y' )
FROM   (
         SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + FLOOR( (LEVEL - 1) / 15 )
                  + FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 16)) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
                  AS dt
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY
                DATE '2020-01-01' + FLOOR( (LEVEL - 1) / 15 )
                  < ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2020-01-01', 12 )
       )
```

Which for the table:

```
  dt         DATE
             NOT NULL,
  is_workday CHAR(1)
             NOT NULL
             CONSTRAINT calendar_date2__iwd__chk CHECK ( is_workday IN ( 'Y', 'N' ) )
);
```

Gives you 15 rows for each day of 2020 each with random offset between 1 and 15 minutes from midnight.

*Note:*

- The number of days in the year is calculated so you do not need to account for leap years.
- Use `FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 16 ) )` rather than `ROUND( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 15 ) )` as the first will give you an even spread of values whereas the second will only give a value 1 when the random value is between 1 and 1.5 and a value of 15 between 14.5 and 15 which will both occur with only half the frequency as the rest of the numbers and would give you an unbalanced distribution.
- You can calculate the day of the week by comparing the start of the day `TRUNC( dt )` to the start of the ISO week `TRUNC( dt, 'IW' )`. This has the benefit that it is independent of the NLS settings and will work in all languages rather than just being limited to English speaking territories.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7aa63e96cd0ddd90338e3062bd7119ab)*

Comment: awesome man worked I don't need of each 15 days of every day so i removed `/15` and it worked fine is it possible i want time with mytime mean if i need random time between `for random(07:45 am to 8:am am)`  and it gives me this and want to make condition if variable(shift) have value A Then it start from `07:45 am to 5:00 pm` if B then `for random(04:45 pm to 5:00 pm)` please help me @MTO

Comment: @MTO I tried this `SELECT DATE ((to_date('01.01.2020 07:45', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'))) + FLOOR( (LEVEL - 1))` in replacement of `SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + FLOOR( (LEVEL - 1) / 15 )` but not worked

Comment: @aws Something like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=578c5c7a9424f7f7cb9531e3b0b8b066)?

Comment: @MTO how much I thankfull to you Beleive me you wont think this I am working on this previous 15 days but didnt get it you awasome, superb what i can say you bbbbuuuuuuunnnnnndddddlllllle of thanks to u

Comment: @MTO Dear plz I hava a tables named EMPLOYEES, Pay_IN_OUT and SHIFT_TIMINGS where Employees have a EMPLOYEE_ID1, SHIFT and WEEKREST column and SHIFT_TIMINGS have column SHIFT and Shift start Time in table Pay_IN_OUT have TIME_IN,EMPLOYEE_ID1,IS_WORK_DAY. Dear I want that it select employee id, weekrest and shift from employees and then shif time checked from  shift timings and weekrest if sunday than is_workday *N*  else which weekrest have a day that is mentioned insert ino pay_in _out like this `10001, 1/1/2020 7:55:00 AM, y` mean in pay_in_out `employee_id1, datetime, is_work_day, weekrest`

Comment: Please ask a new question as that is beyond the scope of this one and I am not able to address ever expanding questions through comments.

Comment: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380462/inserting-data-in-a-table-from-matching-two-table-with-auto-generating-date-and) @MTO